# Doubts on methods of Method Class in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have read http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Method.html.
I have some doubts on methods of `Method` class:

1. What is the difference between `name` and `original_name`?
2. Would `source_loction` give `nil` for ruby gem related `Method` objects?
3. I have seen the `receiver` would give the bound receiver of method object. What is the meaning of bound receiver?

Is there anyway to distinguish between the method created by `def <method_name> ..... end` and `define_method(symbol){block}`?

Comment: Please ask one question per thread except for strongly connected questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. *What is the difference between `name` and `original_name`?*

   `original_name` returns the original name for [aliased methods](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/miscellaneous_rdoc.html#label-alias):

   ```
   def foo; end
   alias bar foo

   method(:bar).name          #=> :bar
   method(:bar).original_name #=> :foo
   ```
2. *Would `source_loction` give `nil` for ruby gem related `Method` objects?*

   [`source_location`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Method.html#method-i-source_location) works for gems, too:

   ```
   require 'rails'
   Rails.method(:version).source_location
   #=> [".../ruby/2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/version.rb", 5]
   ```

   It returns `nil` for native methods, i.e. methods written in C:

   ```
   method(:puts).source_location #=> nil
   ```
3. *I have seen the receiver would give the bound receiver of method object. What is the meaning of bound receiver?*

   Bound methods are associated with a particular object (the receiver) and can be called, e.g.:

   ```
   str = "abc"
   str.method(:upcase) #=> #<Method: String#upcase>
   ```

   [`instance_method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Module.html#method-i-instance_method) returns the method as an unbound method:

   ```
   String.instance_method(:upcase) #=> #<UnboundMethod: String#upcase>
   ```

   [`UnboundMethod`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/UnboundMethod.html) doesn't have a receiver and can't be called (there's no string instance you could upcase).
4. *Is there anyway to distinguish between the method created by `def <method_name> ..... end` and `define_method(symbol){block}`?*

   I don't think so.